# Find a special character in a table and remove it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains special characters I want to get rid of.

Example:

[image]

And this is the text (I pasted the pic because the character isn't visible in the text version)

```
enominazione AOC. I vini di b
```

I've got the ASCII code of this character using the `ASCII()` function and it returned `11`.

The problem is when I execute this query :

```
DECLARE @specharfilter NVARCHAR(10) = CHAR(11);
SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE [Text] like N'%' + @specharfilter + N'%'
```

I don't get any result. On the other hand, when I try with another ascii code like `70` I get results.

So what am I doing wrong ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't recreate this issue, seems to work fine for me: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1a14f370e4681536a20250bd51f6ab5d You also realise that you populate the variable but never actually use it?

Comment: Even with your edit and using the variable, I am still unable to reproduce this behaviour. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=dc307e31eeccd89adb3b521a4db57e69

Comment: You're right. After trying your example, I found out that there were some issues with my table (unrelated to this topic). I fixed them and now I get the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PATINDEX()` probably like

```
SELECT * FROM My_Table 
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^0-9][^a-z][^A-Z]%',Col1) > 0
```

Comment: The lack of explanation makes it very difficult to understand where you have gone wrong (mostly because I can't tell what this query was trying to achieve), but it will return a patindex of 0 when the text contains special character, e.g. `SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9][^a-z][^A-Z]%', NCHAR(11) + 'Test')`, and will return aa patindex greater than 0 when the text doesn't contain special characters, e.g. `SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9][^a-z][^A-Z]%', 'A4 ')`. So I think the logic is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

If interested in a UDF, the following function will strip control characters from a string and NOT concatinate words.

**Example:**

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control]('Michael        '+char(13)+char(10)+'LastName')
```

**Returns**

```
Michael LastName   -- << No CRLF or extra spaces and
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](@S varchar(max))
Returns varchar(max)
Begin
    ;with  cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(C) As (Select Top (32) Char(Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))-1) From cte1 a,cte1 b)
    Select @S = Replace(@S,C,' ')
     From  cte2

    Return LTrim(RTrim(Replace(Replace(Replace(@S,' ','><'),'<>',''),'><',' ')))
End
```